# Eclipse install Graphviz

Tags: eclipse, graphviz

Does anyone know how to install Graphviz on Eclipse?

I installed it from http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php for Windows (`.msi`). The installation was successful but (maybe I added to Eclipse wrongly) it gaves me this error when I tried to compile it with my project:

```
Couldn't create graphs with 'dot'. Is graphviz installed? Is graphviz/bin added to the system variables?
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you give more details about your code that uses Graphviz and how you compile your (Java, C/C++, ...?) code?

Comment: thanks i solved it i didnt add the environmental variable to the system. and it was java